# How to avoid images being refreshed in UITableViewCell on scroll?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have implemented custom NSCache to store the remotely downloaded images that are displayed in my `UITableViewCells`. Note that the images are being downloaded asynchronously.

However, if I scroll up and down quickly, I can still see images being refreshed even if the images are from local. Anyone can help me understand how to avoid the refreshing issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "refreshing"? Is it trying download the images again or there are some glitches in the loaded image for a while? ALso, show some code please.

Comment: You need to use cell with tag.

Comment: Praveen, I did. But I used a static tag for the cell. That is the entire table used a cell with the same tag. Should i use different tags for the image buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good practice to reuse tableView cells so you'll need to update the images at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, otherwise the images will be messed.

There're some optimizations i could suggest however:

- improve the cache performance to make the images loading faster,
- use a standard or a custom tag when adding images to the cell imageView, at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` compare the cell's image tag value with a combination of cell index/row numbers (like section*1000 + row) using this formula as a hash-indicator. This should let you know whether you really need to update a displayed image and will probably save you some cache-reading operations,
- if the images loaded are large and you are using resized versions to display over the cells, store the thumbnails separately - this will save you the resizing operations which might be quite expensive,
- make sure you are reloading the images that you already have in cache if they are outdated, it's also important not to perform the check too frequent as a large amount of the HTTP request will make the application looking slow as well as drain the battery faster (not to mention an annoying activity indicator at status bar, as a user i'd prefer to see at as rarely as possible).

Hope it helps.

---

In the situation when you have a lot of cells, most of them will be reused, not created.
If you are adding a button with `addSubview` for any cell, the reused cell will already have it added, the labels text, images will be also reused.

In this situation you might want to check whether you need to set a new image to the existing button. One of the simple ways is to store the cell's section and row number at image tag (or cell tag, or button tag, whatever), the formula is used to store two numbers in a single attribute. **It will let you know the section/row numbers of the cell you've got to reuse.**

It's not always effective and you could come to a better solution depending on what you have and need.

Comment: hmmm...now i think it could be the problem of image resizing, let me go check :)

Comment: A-Live, I now think the problem is within the 2nd point u mentioned. However, could you please explain to me what you meant by use a standard or custom tag? Is it the tag for images? or the tag to the UIButton that has the image? Thanks!

Comment: Edited an answer, a standard tag is `UIView` property `NSInteger tag`, in some situations you will want to have a text/bool/enum tag, i would do it by subclassing and adding the properties i need.

Comment: Thanks a lot, A-Live! When I create the UITable to show a list of results, I dequeued the customized table cell first, so the cell can be reused. Within this cell, there is an image displayed and I set it as button's image so it is clickable. Within this table, the images on the cells are different.

My confusions:
1. In this case, do i need to set tag for each image/button?
2. When scrolling down the table, after a while, then I scroll up again, I can see images being repainted some times but not always. I think probably like u said, i should improve my cache to cache images after cropping

Comment: @nanshi what you can do to diagnose the problem is to analyze the cache access time by logging the cache read start/end. If that is a few ns, then the problem is most likely at UI handling, but it might be also useful to analyze the concurrent reading - it can happen that your read operations are synchronous. Regarding the first question, yes, you will want to check if the image needs to be updated for every cell (as the first initialized cell will be also reused if you scroll down and then scroll back to the top). But i would first analyze the problem to know exactly what to improve.

Comment: A-Live, thanks a lot for spending time to explain things in many details. I think you gave me the right direction, I will investigate this tonight to find the bottle neck and post back. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method in your TableView delegate, you need to check if the image is in your cache, if not you need to download it.  If it is present you need to set the cell's image to the version in your cache.  I would assume you are not pulling the image from the cache and instead re-downloading it.

Comment: I did double check to make sure the images are loaded from cache if it's available from the cache.